# Does Spotlight index dotfiles (OS X Yosemite)?

Tags: spotlight, macos

I want to create an Alfred workflow with some dotfiles (i.e. zsh config files).

Long story short, in Alfred, I only can play with files indexed by Spotlight. 
Apparently, Spotlight doesn't index dotfiles as I can't get any dotfile in my Alfred results.

Any of my Spotlight setting that would force Spotlight to index dotfiles index is checked.

So, my question is there a way to force Spotlight to index dotfiles, dotfiles of a specific directory, a specific dotfile?

Answer (score 5):

Using the [mdfind](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) command which queries the Spotlight Database I have to say no because the tests I performed would indicate so.  In a Terminal using `mdfind -name .bash_history` as well as subsequent commands changing the `.filename` portion of the command, `mdfind` did not return the specific file names while only returning filenames that contained the `.filename` portion within where applicable.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your fast answer. This limitation is certainly due to Apple security policy.

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight indexes dotfiles. You can see this in Finder by typing ⌘-f and then changing the criteria to include File Visibility and then set it to "Invisible" before performing the search.

I don't know whether Alfred provides this option, but you can achieve the same thing if Alfred allows you to query on arbitary Spotlight metadata. The query you'd add is "kMDItemFSInvisible == 1"